# Openfiledialog shows the full path with backslashes in filename box in C#

Tags: c#, filenames, openfiledialog

OpenFileDialog object which has `RestoreDirectory=True` shows the filename as fullpath same as the filename selected before. In the first time I open the dialog it works normally, but in the others it shows the fullpath like in below images.

**First opening of OpenFileDialog**
[image]

**Second opening**

[image]

What is the reason of this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Set filename empty before Show Dialog:

```
openFileDialog1.FileName = string.Empty;
openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
```

but if you need the directory:

```
openFileDialog1.FileName = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(openFileDialog1.FileName);
openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
```